# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Tags: php, syntax

I've been working on something for the past few days but this one bit of code perpetually throws an unexpected T_ECHO.  My friends can't seem to find anything wrong with it and I'm at the edge of my patience.  Even with the nested while loop removed it still throws an error and I switched to the while: endwhile; syntax as well and I'm still getting it.  I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but I probably can't see it.

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)):        
            echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>". $row["site_description"] ."</td>";
              echo "<td>". $row["url"] ."</td>";
              echo "<td><select>";
                while ($roar = mysql_fetch_array($categories, MYSQL_ASSOC)):
                  echo "<option value=\"". $roar["category"] ."\">". $roar["category"] ."</option>";
                endwhile;
              echo "</select></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          endwhile;
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that code is giving the error? Is it possible that you're running a different file?

Comment: to which line number / which echo error reffering to ? this peace of code is correct

Comment: That code works fine. Are you sure the error's occuring here? As well, any reason you're using the alternate block syntax instead of the usual `{}`?

Comment: the line number always refers to the line immediately following the nested while loop echo "</select></td>";  i switched because i've been trying everything to try to fix it.  and i'm sure it's that code because i've moved around stuff and the line number changes with my edits.  i didn't want to post the entire 115 lines.

Comment: I actually didn't know php supported a completely different syntax. Grr php is always giving everyone arbitrary choices to make your life more difficult.

Comment: i used the alternate syntax because at this point i'm like wondering if it's "magic" that's causing the error 

http://pastebin.com/x80jEYyS of the larger context, line 105 is the offending bit according to the error.

Comment: also i mean i'm sure i'm running this file because if i make an edit to it that changes the line number count the Parse error moves around with that echo "</select...

Comment: Quick suggestion - it might be better to the select contents just the once and put it into a $select_options variable.

Comment: @doug: it's intended for when you're liberally sprinkling small PHP blocks around inside some other text (like HTML). seeing `<?php endwhile ?>` makes it a bit more explicit as to what the snippet is doing, as a simple `<?php } ?>` by itself doesn't mean very much at all. but otherwise, yeah, it's a pain.

Answer (score 2):

You could use short tags to make this far more readable and likely less error prone.

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row["site_description"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["url"] ?></td>
        <td>
            <select>
            <?php while ($roar = mysql_fetch_array($categories, MYSQL_ASSOC)): ?>
                <option><?= $roar["category"] ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Short tags are not xml compliant and should be avoided.

Comment: The short tags for PHP don't ever get seen by the browser - how can they be non-compliant?

Comment: @tandu You've got that all wrong. Of course PHP code isn't XML complaint! Unnecessary downvote!

Comment: @Gary The documentation in `php.ini` suggests against using short tags: "Using short tags should be avoided when developing applications or libraries that are meant for redistribution, or deployment on PHP servers which are not under your control, because short tags may not be supported on the target server."

Comment: @Michael it only suggests against using them if you're distributing the code. If you're concerned about that replace `<?=` with `<?php echo`. that type of inline coding still makes for far more readable code.

Comment: @James Yeah I always use `<?php echo`.  Also, like in your code sample, I like to separate the HTML from the PHP code.  This is good for IDEs because then, it will syntax color the HTML and also provide auto-completion for the HTML.

Comment: If you have a php file with an xml declaration and short tags enabled, you will run into some problems.  Readability is also an opinion, but I think that neither breaking out of php nor echoing immediately is a good idea (unless we're debugging).  These are antiquated notions.  HTML should be built and displayed when ready.

Comment: @tandu - if you have any PHP file with an XML declaration and short tags enabled won't you run into problems? Could you give some concrete examples? I'm really curious!

Comment: @tandu - Yes, I'd really like to see an example of the problem that you describe too. The idea that either echoing or breaking out of php are "antiquated notions" will come as a considerable surprise to the hundreds of thousands of PHP developers out there!

Comment: @Michael - Oh sure, I'd not generally recommend short tags. I was just responding to statement saying "Short tags are not xml compliant and should be avoided" = which is nonsensical in the context of PHP

Comment: @tandu @James @Gary If I understand tandu correctly, he's saying that if you are using PHP to generate an XML document, and you are using short tags, then the file will fail validation if you try to validate the file as an XML file.  For example: `<root><tag1><?=$foo?></tag1></root>` will fail validation even though it's a perfectly good XML document.

Comment: @Michael is more or less correct; you can't create an xml declaration in a php file with short tags enabled as well. @Gary that is because there are hundreds of thousands of subpar PHP developers out there.

Comment: @tandu Oh I see.  PHP will throw a parse error on: `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`.

Comment: ah OK, unless you do `echo('<'.'?xml version="1.0" ?'.'>');` or similar

Comment: @James C yes that is true, there are a lot of possible solutions for it such as the one you stated.

Comment: in terms of best practice I would always suggest building XML as a simpleXMl object and then rendering it. I've run into enough problems trying to hand build XML in the past.

Comment: @tandu I'll mention that to the guys at salesforce.com when I see them next!

Comment: @Gary I'm not sure if you're being ironic or throwing around the name salesforce to sound impressive, but their website was an example of exactly what /not/ to design when we were creating our financial analytics application (obviously we could not see the php code) so they do not impress me.  The salesforce concept is also on its way out IMO, but that is a separate discussion.

Comment: @Gary What does XML have to do with Salesforce?

Comment: @Michael - my apols it was an off topic reference to another o/t remark that I find absurd, that's all. @tandu - I was being ironic, but I do really really disagree with you... (I suspect that we'll have to agree to disagree, and that neither of us will lose any sleep as a consequence!)

Comment: @sqn - sorry! Did you get the result you needed?

Comment: sadly something urgent came up and has put the script on the sidelines, by tomorrow it should be resolved, sorry for the anticlimax ( ° _ °)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I think it may have been falling over because once you've parsed the categories resultset, for the first site, it comes up with nothing the next time you call mysql_fetch_array. So, doing this upfront and popping the results into a variable fixes that.

I've added "\t" and "\n" to the strings to make the html format prettily in view source.

```
    $result = mysql_query("select * from tmp_sites");
$categories = mysql_query("select * from tmp_cats");
$select_options = "";
while ($roar = mysql_fetch_array($categories, MYSQL_ASSOC)):
                  $select_options .= "\t\t<option value=\"". $roar["category"] ."\">". $roar["category"] ."</option>\n";
                endwhile;
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)):
            echo "\t<tr>\n";
              echo "\t\t<td>". $row["site_description"] ."</td>\n";
              echo "\t\t<td>". $row["url"] ."</td>\n";
              echo "\t\t<td><select>\n";
                echo $select_options;
              echo "\t\t</select></td>\n";
            echo "\t</tr>\n";
          endwhile;
echo "</table>"
```